# ActiveRecord transactions, saving 1000+ entries

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, transactions

I have EventsController create action that looks like this:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @event = Event.new(params[:event].slice(*Event.accessible_attributes))
    if @event.save
      DraftBuilder.new(event: @event).build(params[:event][:file].path) 
      redirect_to @event
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

end
```

**params[:event][:file]** is a file that user can submit through Event#new action via file_field_tag.

**DraftBuilder#build** method, among many other things, parses a given file and creates about 1000 records in a database(saves data to database across several tables).

Problem I have is that DraftBuilder#build is really slow. It is slow because I'am saving records in a loop and Active Record creates new transaction for every save.

Simplified DraftBuilder#build might look like this:

```
class DraftBuilder
  def build(file)
    @data = parse(file) #@data is an array of hashes with 1000+ records
    @data.each do |pick_arguments|
      Pick.create(pick_arguments)
    end
  end
end
```

I found one solution to this problem. Wrap controller create action in to ActiveRecord::Base.transaction:

```
class EventsController < ApplicationController
  around_filter :transactions_filter, only: [:create]

    def transactions_filter
      ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
        yield
      end
    end
end
```

While this solution is working, creates just one transaction, and speeds the whole process by about 60 times. Is it a good way to tackle this problem?? Surely transactions haven't been design for this?? What are the other options for creating records from files with more then thousand entries??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best solution to slow running processes is to use background jobs like [delayed_job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) or [resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque) or [sidekiq](http://mperham.github.com/sidekiq/).

Comment: I think I have seen some Railscasts about delayed_jobs and sidekiq, I need to check it. And I'll need to add some 'processing notification' to events/show.erb.html, because its going to fire **redirect_to @event** straight away. Right?

Answer (score 2):

You have two ways:

Instead of

```
@data.each do |pick_arguments|
  Pick.create(pick_arguments)
end
```

1. Transactions

   ```
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      @data.each do |pick_arguments|
        Pick.create(pick_arguments)
      end
    end
   ```
2. Gem activerecord-import

   ```
   data = []
   @data.each do |pick_arguments|
     data << Pick.new(pick_arguments)
   end
   Pick.import data
   ```

Comment: And as they said, you can use a delayed_job task to answer the user right away and process the task in the background, and even Transactions wasn't thought as a way to make bulk inserts, its a common pattern in ActiveRecord.

Comment: delayed_job or resque or sidekiq do what i need. I think Your suggestion about pushing transaction block out of controller down to DraftBuilder object is as well worth mentioning because I don't think that anyone who will be looking at controller need to know "how the cat is skinned" so +1 ... when ill be able to:)